# Find Camera IP address and subnet mask

Tags: networking, camera

I have an Ethernet camera which is directly connected to my Ubunut machine via  Ethernet cable. I only know the MAC address of the camera and don't know its IP address or its subnet mask. I think that the camera has a static IP.

I found many questions regarding this problem and most of the people suggested using `nmap`. The problem is that I'm not sure what is the subnet mask the should be used with nmap and I have no experience about networking.

I tried something like (as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79691)):

```
nmap -sn 134.109.133.0/24
```

Then

```
arp -an | grep -v incomplete
```

But the output was NULL

I also tried `wireshark` and `avahi-discover` but didn't work.

Could someone help me with this please?

Comment: What subnet masks did you try, specifically? Did you try anything other than the one in your question?

Comment: Yes. I suspected two subnet masks an tried both of them but didn't work

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/jldupont/mdns-browser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have a laptop I use at client sites for issues like this.  I run wireshark to see what's on the network, and what traffic the device generates.

Ideally, you have just the host with wireshark and the device you are trying to manage, connected via ethernet to a switch, and nothing else connected.  With the host powered up, and the device powered down, launch wireshark and begin a capture session on the ethernet.  Power up the device and you will see what the device is using to communicate on the wire.

you may need a cross-over cable if you have the device connected via ethernet directly to your computer's ethernet port.

Good luck!

Comment: Many thanks @BISI. It worked and now I can reach the camera.
I tried to make the camera IP DHCP and I expected that I will be able to reach the camera without setting the IP address and the subnet mask of my PC each time but it didn't work. I don't know why! Therefore, I reset it to be static. Any suggestion how can I reach the camera without having to reset the IP address of my PC each time?

Comment: a hard reset on the camera?  Update firmware for it?  it's not clear that your camera  is successfully getting config info from the DHCP server.  If both your computer and your camera *are* getting their configuration information from the same DHCP server, then you should be able to reach the camera from any device on the LAN.  You can use wireshark, and filter on the known MAC address of the camera to troubleshoot the DHCP issue.

Comment: Yes, this, and most IP cameras use port 554, so if you can find traffic to and from port 554 with wireshark or tcpdump - that's the camera most likely

Answer (score 0):

`arp -a` should provide the results that you need. The output is in the format:

> ? (IP-address) at MAC Address [interface type] on interface name

If you get no output odds are very good that you aren't connected.